# MAUI How to Access XAML Map VisibleRegion in ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, maui

I have a MAUI map control in XAML and I need to access the VisibleRegion property in the ViewModel, but the property is not bindable.  Can anyone help me think of a work-around how to access this information in the ViewModel?

This is the XAML

```
<maps:Map x:Name="mapStoresNearby"
    MapType="Street"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MapPins}">
    <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MapPin">
        <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
        Address="{Binding Address}"
        Label="{Binding Label}" 
        Type="{Binding Type}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
</maps:Map>
```

I need to access these properties in the View Model, but cannot figure out how to send the information from the View to the ViewModel.

```
    mapStoresNearby.VisibleRegion.Center.Latitude;
    mapStoresNearby.VisibleRegion.Center.Longitude;
    mapStoresNearby.VisibleRegion.Radius.Miles;
```

I can access the VisibleRegion in the code behind, is there a proper way to pass them to the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `VisibleRegion` is not bindable, we cannot directly bind it in ViewModel. But since you could get it in code behind, then it can be passed to  ViewModel.

We could use `PropertyChanged` event handler to detect `VisibleRegion` Property changes.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mapStoresNearby.PropertyChanged += Map_PropertyChanged;
    this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}


private void Map_PropertyChanged(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == nameof(Map.VisibleRegion))
    {
        //Suppose there is a Property called MyVisibleRegion which stores the VisibleRegion value
        (BindingContext as MainPageViewModel).MyVisibleRegion = mapStoresNearby.VisibleRegion;

    }
}
```

From the above code, each time `VisibleRegion` Property changes, the `Map_PropertyChanged` will be invoked. Thus we could pass the `VisibleRegion` Property value to the ViewModel.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is a good workaround. The only issue I see when you move the Map, for me above is called multiple (3) times, rather than calling it once like Map Pan event in actual Android SDK.